# PhoneGap link to Google Play

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I use Cordova and PhoneGap to make my App
I tryed to create a link to Google Play from App

```
<a href="market://details?id=com.restaurant.start">LINK</a>
```

But it is not work

Answer (score 2):

First you need to use Cordova/PhoneGap InAppBrowser plugin to redirect links to system instead of opening inside the App.

Install Plugin :

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

After installing the plugin write a function to redirect the links to system. Code below.

```
function openExternal(elem) {
    window.open(elem.href, "_system");
    return false; // Prevent execution of the default onClick handler 
}
```

Then in your HTML file add the link as :

```
<a href="market://details?id=com.restaurant.start" onClick="javascript:return openExternal(this)">LINK</a>
```

Now the links should be redirected to system and you can choose browser or PlayStore to resolve the URL.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<a onclick="redirect();"   id="addImage" style="background-color: #30739A;" ></a>
 function redirect()
{


        window.location = 'userlink';
}
```

Comment: I want to open Google Play on user's device...Not Google Chrome